# How do I clear a filterList without getItemCount returning zero?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I have a filterList in the RecyclerView Adapter file that filters a list of CardView items.  When I click on the action_search MenuItem to launch a SearchView on the list, the filterList is cleared and the search is returned.  I have an EmptyRecyclerView class that runs a checkIfEmpty() that returns a default CardView when there are no cards in the list (when getItemCount() == 0).  My problem is every time I run the filter() method in the Adapter, the filterList is cleared and getItemCount() == 0 and the View flips to the default CardView.  The filterList.clear() is only used temporarily because the final filterList is immediately returns the matching items from the SearchView.  How can I avoid the View flipping when the filterList.clear() makes getItemCount == 0?

Main Activity.java

```
...
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.cardview_menu, menu);
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);

    if (adapter == null || adapter.getItemCount() == 0) {
        item.setVisible(false);
    } else {
        item.setVisible(true);
        // Get the SearchView and set the searchable configuration
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
        searchView.setQueryHint(" Search here...");
    }
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Adapter

```
public class MyRecylerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

   private List<ListItem> listItems, filterList;
   private Context mContext;
   public boolean mFilterSearch = false;  \\ *** added
   ...
   public MyRecylerAdapter(Context context, List<ListItem> listItems) {
    this.listItems = listItems;
    this.mContext = context;
    this.filterList = new ArrayList<>();
    this.filterList.addAll(this.listItems);
}

    public void clear() {
        while (getItemCount() > 0) {
        remove(getItem(0));
    }
}

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return (null!= filterList ? filterList.size() : 0);
    }

    public void filter(final String text) {

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                mFilterSearch = true;  \\ *** added
                filterList.clear();  

                // If there is no search value, then add all original list items to filter list
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(text)) {
                    filterList.addAll(listItems);
                }
                else {

                    // Iterate in the original List and add it to filter list...
                    for (ListItem item : listItems) {  
                    ...  
                    mFilterSearch = false; \\ *** added
```

EmptyRecyclerView

```
public class EmptyRecyclerView extends RecyclerView {

private View emptyView;
private MyRecyclerAdapter adapter;
...
void checkIfEmpty() {
    if (adapter.mFilterSearch = false && emptyView != null && getAdapter() != null) { \\ *** added "adapter.mFilterSearch &&"
        final boolean emptyViewVisible =
                getAdapter().getItemCount() == 0;
        emptyView.setVisibility(emptyViewVisible ? VISIBLE : GONE);
        setVisibility(emptyViewVisible ? GONE : VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

Comment: instead of clearing `filterList` use smart algorithm to remove un searched item and remove those from filterList, or set one boolean value in start of `filter` method and set it back after your search has been done, then in `checkIfEmpty` check `if (needToCheck && emptyView != null && getAdapter() != null)`

Comment: So set up a global int variable and then have filter method trigger it.  Then have checkIfEmpty method check the variable and if it was triggered then do not show the Empty View?

Comment: I used a global int variable and made it static and then used if(Adapter.search !=1 && emptyView ! = null...)  That worked to keep the default CardView from loading but I lost the CardViews for the existing RecyclerView items...I had a blank View.  If I back out of the app and then re-launch it, the item View appears as expected.  What am I missing here?

Comment: why use `int` value ? use `boolean` is not better than it?
I think you don't change `int` or `boolean` value after your work done, you need set it and change it in `filter` method. did you do that?

Comment: @ shayan pourvatan Ok I revised the code above to include a boolean as you recommended.  In the EmptyRecylerView class, I get the following warning on the "if (adapter...) line":  The Condition is always false.  How can it always be false if I set it to true in the filter method?  What am I missing here?

Comment: might you don't have call filter method anywhere in your project, if you call filter method warning must be disappeared.